How to override default backoff period and max retries on Aiven JdbcSinkConnector
I am using the Aiven JdbcSinkConnector (io.aiven.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector) to connect to Postgres DB.
I want to set up custom backoff time and max retries number but it seems not possible, it always fails to default ones (10000 ms and 3).
Does someone know how and where I can set up properties that will be used to override this?
This is the exception I received when my DB is not available:
Unable to connect to database on attempt 1/3. Will retry in 10000 ms. (io.aiven.connect.jdbc.util.CachedConnectionProvider:97)
I am creating the sink connector with the following POST command but this does not work:
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{
    "name": "jdbc-sink-my-topic", "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.aiven.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://localhost:8081",
    "tasks.max": 1,
    "connection.url": "jdbc:postgresql://<private_ip>/<db_name>?currentSchema=<schema_name>",
    "connection.user": <username>,
    "connection.password": <password>,
    "connection.attempts": 5,
    "connection.backoff.ms": 20000,
    "topics": <topic_name>,
    "table.name.format": <db_table_name>,
    "insert.mode": "multi",
    "pk.mode": "none",
    "auto.create": "false",
    "errors.tolerance": "all",
    "errors.log.enable": "true",
    "errors.log.include.messages": "true"}}' http://localhost:8083/connectors | jq


Please open an issue at https://github.com/Aiven-Open/jdbc-connector-for-apache-kafka/issues

It's not supported. The constructor that uses the non-default backoff is only used for the JDBCSource Task, not the Sink.
https://github.com/Aiven-Open/jdbc-connector-for-apache-kafka/blob/master/src/main/java/io/aiven/connect/jdbc/util/CachedConnectionProvider.java#L43-L59
